# Magento model rewrite isn't working

Tags: php, magento

I'm going crazy trying to figure this out.  The Module itself is an already existing, working module, so I know it's not anything to do with stuff like /app/etc/Modules/ configs.  I know the rewrite isn't working because I put a similar log statement in the Core file in the same function, and it's the one being hit, not my rewritten function.

Company/Module/etc/config.xml

```
<global>
  <models>
    <core>
      <rewrite>
        <email_template_filter>Company_Module_Model_Email_Template_Filter</email_template_filter>
      </rewrite>
    </core>
  </models>
</global>
```

Company/Module/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php:

```
class Company_Module_Model_Email_Template_Filter extends Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter
{

    public function skinDirective($construction)
    {
        echo "hello";
    }
}
```

Comment: What does this print our `echo get_class(Mage::getModel('core/email_template_filter'))` ?

Comment: this is correct (technically I mean, you should format it better): not a cache issue?

Comment: @Marius   I get this:    Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter

Comment: This means that there is something wrong in your rewrite procedure. Either your module is not loaded or the `config.xml` is not formatted properly. Please post your entire module in the question. I mean files. `app/etc/modules/Company_Module.xml` `app/code/local/Company/Module/etc/config.xml` and any other files you may have. But the first 2 are the most important.  Also try clearing the cache, but I don't think this will do you any good.

Comment: K, so now I get Company_Module_Model_Email_Template_Filter,  but when I load a page on my site that uses a CMS block with a skin tag,  it still calls the core file, not my overwritten file.

Answer (score 1):

That's not the class used for filtering e-mail templates. I assume that you are testing it by a cms page, or a cms block.
The class used to filter this entities is dictated by the config path `global/cms/page/template_filter` and `global/cms/block/template_filter`.
That path is defined in the `config.xml` file of `Mage_Cms`:

```
    <cms>
        <page>
            <tempate_filter>cms/template_filter</tempate_filter>
        </page>
        <block>
            <tempate_filter>cms/template_filter</tempate_filter>
        </block>
    </cms>
```

and it is overwritten by the piece of markup in `config.xml` from `Mage_Widget`.

```
    <cms>
        <page>
            <tempate_filter>widget/template_filter</tempate_filter>
        </page>
        <block>
            <tempate_filter>widget/template_filter</tempate_filter>
        </block>
    </cms>
```

So actually for filtering blocks you can try to override `Mage_Widget_Model_Template_Filter`